# Vertical list grouped by record in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'd like to take a [standard SharePoint 2013 list](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4D6D2216DF123DE9!149809&authkey=!AAniValkam-vggM&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png) and display the list items [vertically](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4D6D2216DF123DE9!149810&authkey=!APWDya1pOLbxHho&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png).

I've seen some resources that indicate this can be accomplished on earlier versions of SharePoint, but it is unclear to me as to whether or not this is achievable in SharePoint 2013.

**Current SP List:**

[image: Regular SP List]

**Ideal Vertical SP List:**

[image: Vertical SP List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achive this using JSLink - you can override display logic of list item to anything you want. There is a good article about it: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html